# Zeo/ZODB lock file location, possible to change?

Tags: python, zope, zodb

We recently moved a Zeo instance over to a new server environment and one of the changes was the file system now has the database files stored on an NFS share.

When trying to start zeo, we've been getting lock file errors which after researching seems to be because of a known issue of lock files being created on an NFS share.

My question is, can we maintain the data (.fs) files on the share but have the lock files created on the server's filesystem?  We want to maintain the data being stored on the SAN so moving the data over to box is really not an option.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You will have more problems than just locking on NFS. Rule of thumb is to not put Data.fs files on NFS shares, ever!

Answer (score 1):

This is likely not a good setup.  Your best bet is to work-around NFS in spite of it: maybe *a loopback ext3 filesystem mounted on a regular file on the NFS volume* -- NFSv3 should have few practical limits to filesize that you won't have natively.  Only you will be able to measure if this performs well enough.  Otherwise, you should know that (generally) *no networked database performs well or without side-effects over NFS*.